# =COUNTIF(range, value I am trying to find within the range) makes a mistake, why?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, countif

Formula =COUNTIF(range, value) makes a mistake in my google sheets..It returns 0, but the value that it fails to find within the range actually exists in that range. I checked simply with Ctrl + F command. I wonder why that happens? What could be the reason? Cell formatting?

Please, see screenshot enclosed. Cell "B 3520" returns 0, but in the upper right corner you see "2 of 2", and that 2nd one is within the given range. [image]

Comment: Are you using Google Sheets or Excel? You mention one, but tag the other. It's also hard to diagnose data we don't see.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad You are right! I used the wrong tags!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 I edited the post now. You can see that the formula return 0 for one particular value, whereas it should return 1, because the value exists within the range.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I added a screenshot, hopefully, the situation is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

delete your formulae in B column and try (in row 1):

```
=INDEX(COUNTIF(A:A; A:A))
```

Comment: If i paste exactly this, I get a REF error..Should I modify it somehow?

Comment: @MariaMakarova are you pasting it into empty column into row 1?